# Reference to a primitive operator function

Tags: rust

In Rust, is there any manner to handle operator functions such as add, or sub? I need to get the *reference* for those functions, but I can only find about traits. I'll leave here a comparative of what I need (like the wrapper methods) in Python.

```
A = 1
B = 2
A.__add__(B)

#Or maybe do something more, like
C = int(1).__add__
C(2)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can obtain a function pointer to a trait method of a specific type via the *universal function call syntax*:

```rust
let fptr = <i32 as std::ops::Add>::add;    // type: `fn(i32, i32) -> i32`

fptr(1, 3);   // returns 4
```

Bigger example ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8210140e460342fb62658ebd2dccfd62)):

```rust
use std::ops;

fn calc(a: i32, b: i32, op: fn(i32, i32) -> i32) -> i32 {
    op(a, b)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", calc(2, 5, <i32 as ops::Add>::add));  // prints 7
    println!("{}", calc(2, 5, <i32 as ops::Sub>::sub));  // prints -3
    println!("{}", calc(2, 5, <i32 as ops::Mul>::mul));  // prints 10
}
```

---

Your `int(1).__add__` example is a bit more complicated because we have a partially applied function here. Rust does not have this built into the language, but you can easily use closures to achieve the same effect:

```rust
let op = |b| 1 + b;
op(4); // returns 5
```